# Set maximum bar height in chart.js

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I'm using chart.js in angular using below code,

```
  const myChart = new Chart('myChart', {
          type: 'bar',
          data: {
              labels: ['Mathematics', 'English', 'Physics', 'Chemistry' ],
              datasets: [{
                  label: 'Score',
                  data: [this.mathematics_score,this.english_score,this.physics_score,this.chemistry_score],
                  backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                  ],
                  borderColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                  ],
                  borderWidth: 1,
                 
              }]
          },
          options: {
            indexAxis: 'x',
            responsive: true,
              scales: {
                  x: {
                      beginAtZero: true,
                      min: 0,
                    max: 90
                  }
    
              }
          }
      });
```

Here subjects score is out of 50 but in the graph height is set according to the maximum score got in subject suppose i got 40 in mathematics, 38 in English, 30 and 28 in Physics and chemistry respectively then the maximum value in graph which is set is 40 but i want 50.

Any solution, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to set the max on the x axis while you need to set it on the y axis. If you do that it works as expected:

```js
options: {
  scales: {
    y: {
      max: 50,
    }
  }
}
```